# What could cause this Java UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

The first part of the stack-trace is as follows: "UnsatisfiedLinkError (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.19/jre/lib/i386/libawt.so: libmlib_image.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory):"

Both libawt.so and libmlib_image.so exist and are in the same directory. Does libawt.so look in a different directory? Is there an environment option I'm missing?

This is part of a Rails application using Rjb (ruby-java bridge).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need xorg-libs installed on your host. Also you could try to launch the process using -Dawtheadless=true and see what the result is.

Comment: -Dawtheadless=true (actually, -Djava.awt.headless=true) was already used as an option. Tried -Dawt.headless, -Dawtheadless, and -Djava.awtheadless with the same result. Also installed xorg-libs with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. I believe it was actually a bug in the 1.5 JDK. With some digging you can find the report.

If I recall correctly, the fix was something along the lines of setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH likes this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I hope this helps.